# Rspec - Model testing with before all to set up model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying something which is very common i think but i am not able to do it because of transactional example.

Here is what i am trying to do

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :b
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :a
end
```

For the testcase

```
describe A do
  before(:all) do
    @a = Factory.create :a
    @a.b.create()
    # Lot of other things which is common to all example
  end

  it { expect state_one(@a) }
  it { expect state_two(@a)  }
end
```

What i am trying to do is set up all the precondition for the tests in the before all and have only one expectation per example.The problem is there are no rows in either table A or B in the context of the examples.

Please let me know if it is the correct approach if yes how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a setup like this:

```
  describe A do
    subject do
      create(:a).tap do |a|
        create(:b, a: a)
      end
    end

    before(:all) do
      # Lot of other things which is common to all example
    end

    context 'state_one' do
      it { expect state_one(@a) }
    end

    context 'state_two' do
      it { expect state_two(@a)  }
    end
  end
```

Assuming that you have factories for `a` and `b` and setup their association properly.

Comment: So anything in the subject is persisted and can be used across examples?

Comment: Yes, kind of. subject block get evaluated lazy. Means, `a` is created when it is first used in the example and it can be used across examples.

Comment: Did it help? Let me know if you have any other question.